# What is a 'nail attack'?

Tags: guitar

I heard this term the first time while browsing acoustic covers of songs in Youtube. I tried searching but there seems to be different variations, and none of the tutorials I found were quite clear.

What is it? How is it really done?

Example I found of it being used was here:

Comment: Could it just mean using your nails to attach the string rather than a pick?

Comment: @ggcg I mean, it looks like at first glance, strumming using the nails. I tried but the sound produced is clearly different and there's something different about it that I can't figure out what...

Comment: For one thing you may just not be good at the technique yet.  Your nails might be slight different in shape, thickness, edge etc.  These things all affect the sound.  Classical guitarists devote a lot of energy to shaping the nails.  Then there is special practice for the attack.

Comment: @ggcg Which is why I'm trying to find out how exactly it is done, and what this 'special practice' is you're referring to for the nail attack. Especially if there are different variations.

Comment: "Exactly what is done" is hard to explain which is why lessons with a flamenco instructor would be good.

Comment: After watching this video it seems like this is a self taught technique, not really classical flamenco or other traditional style.  He is describing what he's doing but in another language.  I personally do not like the sound of nails on steel string acoustics.

Answer (score 1):

I think that "nail attack" in that case is used in the same way as "pick attack" is, that is to describe the way the nail "attacks" (touches) the string.

For example the attack can be flat (pick/nail parallel to string) or angled with consequences on tone and volume..